# Program won't print matrix

Tags: c, pointers, matrix

I've been trying to make a matrix calculator for class where the user inputs the details for a matrix (number of rows, columns, etc.) then prints the input. End result's supposed to look like this:

Ex: 2x2 matrix

1 2

3 4

I looked at some of the similar questions like this one: [Print a square matrix using pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21075798/print-a-square-matrix-using-pointers) but I don't think it's what I'm looking for. This is the code:

```
int **theAMatrix;

switch(choice) {
    case 1:
        theAMatrix = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int*)*rowsizeA);
        for(i = 0; i < rowsizeA; i++) {
            for(j = 0; j < colsizeA; j++) {
            theAMatrix[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*colsizeA);
            }
        }
        for(i = 0; i < rowsizeA; i++){
            for(j = 0; j < colsizeA; j++){
                printf("Enter Row: %d Col: %d ", i, j);
                scanf("%d", &theAMatrix[i][j]);
            }
        }
        printf("Matrix A Complete\n\n");
        Menu();
    case 2:
        printf("Matrix A\n");
        for(i = 0; i < rowsizeA; i++) {
            for(j = 0; j < colsizeA; j++){
                printf("%d", *(*theAMatrix + i) + j);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        Menu();
```

Thing is, the program won't print the matrix when you tell it to. It doesn't crash either, just ends with no fuss. Did I mess up the syntax in some way?

Note: there's a header file with the Menu(), makeChoice(), and getMatrixAValues() functions in it. I already checked it, everything looks good on that front but if anybody thinks something's wrong there I'll post it here too.

[edit] @Joachim this is the code for Menu(), just displays stuff for the user:

```
int Menu() {
    printf("**MATRIX MULTIPLICATION CALCULATOR**\n");
    printf("[1] Enter Matrix A\n");
    printf("[2] Enter Matrix B\n");
    printf("[3] Print Matrix A\n");
    printf("[4] Print Matrix B\n");
    printf("[5] Print Transpose of Matrix A\n");
    printf("[6] Print Transpose of Matrix B\n");
    printf("[7] (bonus) Change size of Matrix A\n");
    printf("[8] (bonus) Change size of Matrix B\n");
    printf("[9] Print A x B\n");
    printf("[0] Exit\n");
    makeChoice();
}
```

Comment: could you add the definition of theAMatrix

Comment: Instead of calling the `Menu()` recursively, it would be better to wrap a loop around the function and `break` out of the `switch` after each case.

Comment: I assume that the code you show is in a function called `Menu`? If so, don't call it recursively, that causes the new function to have all new local variables. Instead use a loop.

Comment: [Please don't cast the return value of `malloc()` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: Is it possible that the allocation of the matrix is buggy? The implementation uses `rowsizeA*colsizeA` calls of `malloc`, while to my understanting it should be either `rowsizeA`or `colsizeA`, depending on whether the matrix is to be stored row-wise or column-size.

Comment: Why don't you use the "AMatrix[i][j]" for printing

Comment: so just theAMatrix = malloc(sizeof(int *)*rowsizeA)?

Comment: Did you intend `case 1:` to fall through into `case 2:`? There is no `break;` statement. And I don't understand why each `case:` contains a call to `Menu()`, why isn't that done first?

Comment: I've just compiled the code in VS2006 and it worked.

Comment: change `printf("%d", *(*theAMatrix + i) + j);` to `printf("%d", *(*(theAMatrix + i) + j));` or `printf("%d", theAMatrix[i][j]);`

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if it is the *real* problem, but logically, you need to add `break;` statements after the `case`.

```
case 1:
    theAMatrix = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int*)*rowsizeA);
    for(i = 0; i < rowsizeA; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < colsizeA; j++) {
        theAMatrix[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*colsizeA);
        }
    }
    for(i = 0; i < rowsizeA; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < colsizeA; j++){
            printf("Enter Row: %d Col: %d ", i, j);
            scanf("%d", &theAMatrix[i][j]);
        }
    }
    printf("Matrix A Complete\n\n");
    Menu();

    // You need a break; statement here!!!
case 2:
    printf("Matrix A\n");
    for(i = 0; i < rowsizeA; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < colsizeA; j++){
            printf("%d", *(*theAMatrix + i) + j);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    Menu();

    // And here as well
```

If that is deliberately done, then I think the way I see it, you call `menu()` in `main()` and the switch-case you have written is part of that `makeChoice()` function.
And if it is so, then may be you can share the snippet where the variable `choice` is getting updated. Can be a silly `scanf` issue.

Did you bother to have a `default:` in the switch case by the way? You can use that to print debug messages just to know if your `choice` is being set properly or not.

Additionally, your `printf("%d", *(*theAMatrix + i) + j);` should be `printf("%d", *(*(theAMatrix + i) + j);`